# Passing paramerets are showing wrong for a Custom Method

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, arguments

I have got a method that i need to call into one of my method and use the string array returned from that method but the parameters that i am passing is not correct.

Here is the method that i am calling into my method..

```
public static string[] ReadFromFile(string filePath, int count, ref int lineCount)
{
     lineCount += count;
     return File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(lineCount).Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

Here is my parameters that i am passing..

```
string filepath="C://Data";
int count;
int lineCount;

string[] arrline= ReadFromFile(filepath,count,lineCount);
```

Please help me where i am wrong.
Thanks ..

Comment: All variables are strings even if you want to use them as counter.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry they are int .I upadted

Comment: Now you pass zero as count which means that you want `Take(0)` lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] arrline= ReadFromFile(filepath,count,ref lineCount);
```

The ref keyword was missing on your passed parameter

Comment: What does this `ref` means .Please elaborate .thanks

Comment: It means you are passing a reference to the integer and not the actual integer value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/14akc2c7.aspx It's is there in this case because you require two different values returned from the method. Any changes you make to the value within the method will be available via the variable you have declared that you have passed into the method.